# Visual Studio Publishing C# .NET Applications

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish

I want to publish a C# application and I don't want to use oneclick or whatever its  called I want to make a single exe so I'm trying to follow this tutorial

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No1paeGvBtw

I'm using Express, the free version of visual studio and my question is can you do this with express because it seems like I cant just open "Visual Studio" I can only open "Visual C#" etc. so at about 2:13 in the video I try to add a new project but the only installed templates are Visual C# and XNA as you can see below
[image]

My questions overall are can I accomplish this with Visual Studio 2010 Express and can I open Visual Studio, not specifically a certain language but generic, like it seems in the video.

Thanks

Edit: I'm in 8th grade so the academic version looks good.

Comment: You could try Wix.  It is free, and builds MSIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create this type of project in Visual Studio Express. Limited functionality is part of what makes it a free product. If you need to create a deployment project, you will need to download a trial of visual studio professional and then you will have this option.

You can see this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx (In the Note section)

UPDATE

You can download a free 90 day trial here: (Which you can later extend by 30 days I believe)

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try

Or if you are set up as a small business you can get it for very cheap from BizSpark (don't remember how much now) from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/Default.aspx

Or you can purchase the Academic Edition:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116948

The rest of the legal options that I am aware of involve paying retail

P.S. The trial version is fully functional that you can use for 4 months.

Comment: Ok, whats the cheapest one where I can do this?  The trial sounds good but what about fully functional non-trial?

Comment: If you're in 8th grade, you should reach out to your school to see what options they have available for you. It is possible that your school is already enrolled with some sort of a licensing deal with Microsoft and can possibly get a copy for you at no charge. - Especially if it's for something school related.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison) has always excluded Setup and Deployment options, but their website used to state that up front.

Previous versions also excluded Windows Mobile applications. VS2010 Express has a Windows 7 Phone version, but does not support the older Windows Mobile devices (i.e. Pocket PCs) at all.

[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is a free, fairly easy tool to create nice setup projects with. It also has an active forum for support.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the free route, use nsis. It is more flexible and less trouble prone anyways. There is an eclipse plugin, I would imagine that there is a visual studio plugin as well.

Here is the VS 2010 nsis plugin. I have never used it, but if it is half as good as eclipse nsis, then it already kicks the visual studio installer templates' ass.
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSISPlus_GUI

Comment: I've used NSIS but how would I go about doing it, take the files from the release folder?

Comment: @Mark: If your project is set to Release mode, Yes. If you are building in Debug mode, get your files from the Debug folder.

Comment: @Mark Just grab all of the files from your Release folder you need to install to the machine and include them in your nsi script. You will also need to make registry entries for menu items, services, desktop icons etc... Anyhow, all of that is easy enough in nsis.